# sed find line in file and remove characters

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that contains lines like this

```
proto udp
.
.
.
..
server 10.10.8.0/24 255.255.255.0
```

I need a way to remove only /24 from this line server 10.10.8.0/24 255.255.255.0
to become

```
server 10.10.8.0 255.255.255.0
```

considering that this line is variable but the only constant thing is the /
it may be like this

```
server 198.196.178.0/8 255.0.0.0
```

so I need a way to remove only /8 from this line to become like this

```
server 198.196.178.0 255.0.0.0
```

Comment: `sed '/^server/s|/[0-9]*||'` may be enough for your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `sed` with captured groups:

```
sed -r 's_^(server\s+([^.]+.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/[0-9]+(.*)_\1\3_' file.txt
```

To edit the file in place, use `-i` option:

```
sed -ri 's_^(server\s+([^.]+.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/[0-9]+(.*)_\1\3_' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% sed -r 's_^(server\s+([^.]+.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/[0-9]+(.*)_\1\3_' <<<'server 10.10.8.0/24 255.255.255.0'
server 10.10.8.0 255.255.255.0

% sed -r 's_^(server\s+([^.]+.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/[0-9]+(.*)_\1\3_' <<<'server 198.196.178.0/8 255.0.0.0' 
server 198.196.178.0 255.0.0.0
```

Comment: thats work but it gives me the output to bash ...i need it to replace it in the file

Comment: @KhalidAboElMaGd No problem, just use `-i` option..check my edits..

Comment: @heemayl, when proposing `sed -i` you should keep in mind two things: (1) For beginners, stress that they **test the command without the `-i` switch** or they may cause damage hard to reverse.  (2) BSD `sed` has a `-i` switch but *requires* a backup extension, even if it's an empty string (i.e. `''`).  When this is omitted the *command* is interpreted as the backup extension, and the filename following it is parsed as a `sed` command (usually leading to errors).  To avoid nasty surprises and for better portability with `-i`, always include a backup extension even if only `''`.

Comment: @Wildcard fair points..OP has already tested without the `-i`, thats why i have suggested it after..check [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270151/sed-find-line-in-file-and-remove-characters/270153?noredirect=1#comment468476_270153)..

Comment: @Wildcard, with GNU `sed`, the backup extension has to be stuck to `-i` which means you can't use `-i ''`. `-i.bak` is portable between GNU and BSDs, but neither `-i` (same as `-i''`) nor `-i ''` are.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, aha—I should have noticed that; it's obvious now you mention it.  I wasn't thinking about what the shell would do with `-i''`.  I guess my point about testing the command before adding the `-i` switch still applies, though.